# Laravel Redisearch package

Tags: laravel, redisearch

I try to use Laravel Redisearch driver by **Ethanhann** for Laravel Scout in my app. I follow the quick tutorial on http://www.ethanhann.com/redisearch-php/laravel-support/ and it works - my model data has been imported as written in this tutorial. 
But if I want to get search results using Scout api like this

`dd(Scout_test::search('some_data')->get());` 
error ocured

`Call to undefined method Ehann\RediSearch\Query\SearchResult::first()`

Anyone use this package as Scout driver?

Comment: are you already do `composer install ethanhann/laravel-redisearch`?

Comment: Yes, of course, all needed packages are installed , I can indexing my models with  **ehann:redisearch:import** command, but Scout search methods did not work..